Is it appropriate to post algorithm designs here for review and comment?
Is it appropriate to post a design of an algorithm to be reviewed and commented on if I provide enough information about it (drawings, technical details)?

@Gilles   That kind of answers my question but I would not be asking for cryptanalysis of my design more can people think of any improvements or can people see any flaws i have missed and can they explain them to me to help me impove

“can people think of any improvements or can people see any flaws” — if your algorithm is about cryptography then this is cryptanalysis (and if your algorithm isn't about cryptography then what would it be doing on this site).

@Gilles Thanks for clarifying do you know any other places where I could post for peer reveiw or improvements?

Post it on iacr and convince people that you have something interesting to say. This is typically done by getting your paper accepted at a crypto research conference. Analysis of a cryptographic algorithm takes years of effort, so it also takes effort to convince people to do it.

@Gilles Thanks this should be helpful but do you know anything more ammetur? because I would only class my skills at a medium level

You may also ask here to try to find people interested to help you.
